# Is this T-SQL statement equivalent with the PL/SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, plsql

Are these two statements equivalent?

```
con_db_connection VARCHAR2 (16) := SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'instance_name)
```

```
DECLARE @con_db_connection VARCHAR(16);
SET @con_db_connection = CONVERT(VARCHAR(16), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceName'));
```

Comment: Note that [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) state that `Instancename` is `nvarchar(128)` which is the same as `sysname`, quite why you are converting it I have no idea,

Comment: @Charlieface I originally had it as a varchar but when I tried executing the proc containing this statement I received an error message on this line (don't remember the details of it now) telling me that I had to convert it.  Once I converted it, the proc worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know **SQL Server**, but - documentation says that `InstanceName` is

> Name of the instance to which the user is connected.
>
> Returns NULL if the instance name is the default instance, if the input is not valid, or error.

As of **Oracle**, `instance_name` parameter returns

> The name of the instance

---

Therefore, if you disregard the `NULL` objection for SQL Server, then yes - I'd say that these two return the same information.

Comment: if I understand it right, the default instance is 'MSSQLSERVER.  That's how I see it as well but my database skills are rudimentary at best so thought I would verify.  Thanks!